# smartglass Nokia Lumia 520 install error

Tags: windows-8

I went to Windows Store in UC browser to download the smartglass app and clicked
the link to download and install manually. After the xap file downloaded i clicked
the file to open it but an error message came up saying that there is a problem with
this company app and requested me to contact the company for assistance. Is it
possible to download and install smartglass manually on a Noka Lumia 520 if it is
not in your Windows Store app?

Answer (score 0):

After much searching I found the answer to this question and decided to post the answer here incase google search users should happen upon it and be relieved. The problem here is that your phone is set to an supported region. You can fix this simply by going to your home screen and tapping settings. Scroll down till you find Language+Region and open it. There  you will find a bar with the header Country/Region. Select it and change it to a supported region; in most cases being US or UK. This is the important step: after changing your region scroll down and tap restart phone. If you do not do this the changes will NOT take effect. After waiting a minute or so your phones region should be changed upon restart.  You can now go to your windows app store and find the app that has stressed you out so much and shout joyfully as you watch it download. Enjoy.